# can we optimize this more to get a unique item repeatring within other items of string in a python list?

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have written this code :

```
words = ['compressed', 'encoded_raw',  'flanc_raw_check', 'tex', 'compressed_raw', 'raw']
matchbox = []
for word in words:
    matches = [w for w in words if  word in w]
    if matches and len(matches) > 1:
        for match in matches:
            print(f'  {match}')
        print('')
        matchbox.append(matches)

print(f' {min(max(matchbox), key=len)}')
```

now I wanted to find out which word in the list of words is unique and also found in other items of the list, like in this the output is raw as it is unique and found within other items of the words list.

Comment: to make sure its unique cast word to a set when iterating over it: `for word in set(words)`

Comment: @joshmeranda fair enough , but objective is if that unique item is also present in other items .

Comment: Is a searched words separated with underscore? I mean: 'raw' is in 'copressed_raw', but can be also in 'raws', 'prawns' etc. If every unique words are separated, than you can prepare `set` on unique words (not items) by splitting items and adding to `set` only words.

Comment: good point, although originally I was just looking for those separated with `_` because otherwise prawn is not raw however compressed_raw is referring raw in compressed still preserving the meaning of raw.